# GlusterFS for simple replication of existing dirs on ext4 FS?

Tags: glusterfs

I have an already existing CentOS 6.9 system with an already existing EXT4 filesystem (/data) housing our application. Certain directories within this file system contain critical per-transaction xml files that our application creates a lot of (very quickly)

e.g.

the EXT4 file system is /data

the directories that need syncing are

- **/data**/some/location/number/one/xml/out
- **/data**/some/location/number/two/xml/out
- **/data**/some/location/number/three/xml/out

These directories are not file systems in their own right, but just dirs within this '/data' EXT4 file system

Using GlusterFS , I want to simply sync (immediately, on write) 'just' the contents of these directories (not anything else in /data) over to the corresponding locations over on a standby box (that has same file structure). This is so that the standby will immediately have all these critical xml files if the main box goes down and we need to fail over to it.. is this possible to do without recreating all the existing EXT4 filesystems?? will it work 'over the top' of the existing FS ?. im having trouble finding config docs for this simple use case.

Also, will this work without any 'clients' in the mix? (remote or local loop mounts) ..I dont need to 'access' the data in any way ..I just need it to be there if the system fails over to standby

Is any of this possible?

Any help would be fabulous :)